# Fire event after mouse moves 200 pixels

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following script to detect mouse movement left or right on an element.

It works great, and depending on the direction, I trigger an image slider to slide left or right. I'm having issues figuring out how to add another variable to this though. I would only like the event to fire after X pixels. So if the mouse is moved left 200 pixels, then the event would fire.

Here's a fiddle of my current setup. http://jsfiddle.net/wMMrh/1/

I've tried adding `if (i++ > 200) { //do something }` to `mousemovement`, but that hasn't helped me.

```
(function ($) {
        var options = {};
        var oldx = 0;
        var direction = "";
        var stop_timeout = false;
        var stop_check_time = 150;
        $.mousedirection = function (opts) {
            var defaults = {};
            options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
            $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
                var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;

                if (e.pageX > oldx) {
                    direction = "right";
                } else if (e.pageX < oldx) {
                    direction = "left";
                }

                clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
                stop_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    direction = "stop";
                    $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
                    $(activeElement).trigger({
                        type: "mousedirection",
                        direction: direction
                    });
                }, stop_check_time);

                $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
                $(activeElement).trigger({
                    type: "mousedirection",
                    direction: direction
                });
                oldx = e.pageX;
            });
        }
    })(jQuery)

    $(function () {
        $.mousedirection();
        $(".iosSlider").bind("mousedirection", function (e) {

            if (!$(".iosSlider").hasClass("moving")) {

            if (e.direction == "left")
                $(".iosSlider").iosSlider('nextSlide');
            else
                $(".iosSlider").iosSlider('prevSlide');
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: First of all, you must save somewhere the initial X axis position of the mouse in a variable(when it begins to move an element). in the `if (e.pageX > oldx) {` test, you must detect if the mouse has moved for more or less than 200 px compared to the variable.

Comment: Are you looking for the total movement to be 200 or more pixels or only the movement that occurs between the 150 millisecond timeout?

Comment: @asymptoticFault `stop_timeout` was set to false. so `stop_check_time`  shouldn't matter.

Comment: The first time the `mousemove` function executes, `stop_timeout` will be set to the timer's handle/id, and your timer will start running.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout for the spec of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldx = null; // note, not equal to 0, since 0 is a valid mouse position
// ...
       $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
            var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;

            clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
            stop_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("timeout!");
                direction = "stop";
                $(activeElement).trigger("stop");
                $(activeElement).trigger({
                    type: "mousedirection",
                    direction: "stop"
                });
            }, stop_check_time);

            if (oldx) {
                var max = +oldx + 200;
                var min = +oldx - 200;
                console.log("e.pageX = " + e.pageX + ", max = " + max + ", min = " + min);
                if (e.pageX > max) {
                    direction = "right";
                } else if (e.pageX < min) {
                    direction = "left";
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("setting oldx to " + e.pageX);
                oldx = +e.pageX;
                return;
            }
            console.log("survived. e.pageX = " + e.pageX);

            // Not sure if you want both triggers here, but I'll assume you do
            $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
            $(activeElement).trigger({
                type: "mousedirection",
                direction: direction
            });
            // changing this to null so my code above will trigger properly next time
            oldx = null;
        });
```

You were close, but needed to do several things.

First, I set `oldx` to `null`, since 0 can be a valid mouse position.  At the bottom, where you had set `oldx` to `e.pageX`, I set it back to `null`.

Next, I set up a max and min variable to check your threshold.  Note the `+oldx`, to make sure that the variable is treated as a number instead of as a string (since "2" + 200 = 2200 instead of 202).

I added lots of console messages to show what's going on.  I'm still working on why the timer results in "right" instead of top.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wMMrh/3/)'s the latest fiddle update.

Comment: I've actually already tried this, and it's not working as desired. Every pixel fires the event.

Comment: @Jako You just need to `return` if you don't set the direction.  Then you won't fire the event until you cross your threshold.

Comment: So what happens when you go 50 pixels right and then 200 pixels left?

Comment: @BlakePlumb Thanks for your question, it made me think more carefully about my answer.  It had been buggy, in that it wouldn't properly save oldx, but now I think I did it as Jako wants.  With my edit now, 50 pixels right + 200 pixels left will result in no event, since the total movement is only 150 pixels left.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein The first edit seemed to be closer (by just adding the else return null), this new rewrite doesn't seem to work at all. It's firing after every pixel move, and returns right for the direction each time.

Comment: @Jako Almost got it.  Your fiddle helped a bunch.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Your fiddle link is the same as mine. I'm still having issues. Do you have an updated fiddle?

Comment: @Jako Finally got it mostly working, and totally rewrote my answer.  I still need to make one fix for the event that happens when your timer triggers, but this should get you started.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Don't worry about the timeout, but I updated the fiddle with your code and it only returns right, not left. http://jsfiddle.net/wMMrh/5/

Comment: @Jako Sorry, got called away to a meeting before I could push the "Save Edits" button.  This one will show a left, but the timeout is still setting it to right, even when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Jako Ok, fixed the mysterious "right" - you had it hard coded at the bottom "if not left, output right".  http://jsfiddle.net/wMMrh/6/

Comment: @Jako No problem.  Sorry it took me so long!